# Implement webassembly in my angular project

Tags: angular, webassembly

I have developed my project over Angular7 and now I want to explore about webAssembly. So how do I convert my recent Web application to WebAssembly?

Comment: Sorry could you please explain what you exactly what to do with web assembly. Web assembly is normally loaded and used from the Javascript of an Webpage so there is not much special handling to be considered for angular

Comment: I have created a project in Angular6 and I want to convert that particular project in WASM, how to do that. Actually I am very much new in Web Assembly and trying to implement in my recent project

Comment: That is not the way you would use web assembly. Web Assembly should be user for computational intensive parts of you application. Its like an Application with parts written in BASIC and other in Assembly. You don't want to write the whole thing in Assembly you would only write time critical things or thinks not possible in BASIC in WebAssembly. But is the oposite in WebAssembly. WebAssembly is more restricted then Javascript so you would need Javascript boilerplate to archive some things like DOM manipulation. Which sometimes is slower then using only Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement angular project with webassembly by following steps

1. You have to instal Web Assembly JavaScript API in you angular project

   `npm install @types/webassembly-js-api --dev --save`
2. Now create you service with C

   `#include <emscripten.h>
    int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE fibonacci(int n)
    {
       if (n == 0 || n == 1)
         return n;
      else
         return (fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
     }`
3. Compiling C to Web Assembly (WASM)

   `emcc wasm/fibonacci.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -o wasm/fibonacci.js`
4. Now create service in Angular

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators'

import * as Module from './../../wasm/fibonacci.js'
import '!!file-loader?name=wasm/fibonacci.wasm!../../wasm/fibonacci.wasm'

@Injectable()
class WasmService {
  module: any

  wasmReady = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)

  constructor() {
    this.instantiateWasm('wasm/fibonacci.wasm')
  }

  private async instantiateWasm(url: string) {
    // fetch the wasm file
    const wasmFile = await fetch(url)

    // convert it into a binary array
    const buffer = await wasmFile.arrayBuffer()
    const binary = new Uint8Array(buffer)

    // create module arguments
    // including the wasm-file
    const moduleArgs = {
      wasmBinary: binary,
      onRuntimeInitialized: () => {
        this.wasmReady.next(true)
      },
    }

    // instantiate the module
    this.module = Module(moduleArgs)
  }

  public fibonacci(input: number): Observable<number> {
    return this.wasmReady.pipe(filter(value => value === true)).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return this.module._fibonacci(input)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

For more reference you can follow this blog https://malcoded.com/posts/web-assembly-angular/

Comment: So services which I have created in angular will be same or do I need to change?

Comment: I am getting this error, while running this command                                            
  npm install @types/webassembly-js-api --dev --save                                                                                      npm  WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated.                           Use `--only=dev` instead.
npm WARN deprecated @types/webassembly-js-api@2.0.0: This is a stub types definition. webassembly-js-api provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: webassembly-js-api@*

Comment: You can use `npm install --only=dev`

Comment: Doesn't work, '_fibonacci' is not a function error...